# Android list of boxes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I wonder if there is a tutorial or example code how the effect below achieved in Android, or if someone published an adapter already for this... Basically based on the number of results returned the screen is populated with boxes, and as the finger swipes down more boxes will load on demand until the results run out.

[image: Skout view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). And you can use your custom Load More GridView. [This](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-dynamicaly) is a custom ListView example of the same. You can implement your own custom GridView similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [Lazy List Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview).

There is a great implementation for it. [You can check it here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). All what you need next is to create the layout of your list rows, i.e the boxes.